# Why does adding product flavors to my libraries build.gradle file cause my local app to be unable to resolve imported dependencies from said library?

Tags: android, gradle, android-productflavors

I'm developing an android application for my company. The project holds directories: our sdk (library in this case) and a sample app that imports the sdk. When I add product flavors to the sdk (library) the app breaks due to being unable to resolve the dependencies imported from the sdk.

The errors are:

1. error cannot find symbol class S
2. error cannot find symbol class SO
3. error package S does not exist
4. error method does not override or
   implement a method from a supertype

Here is the top-level/project level build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
        classpath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.9'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here is the SDK/Library build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.novoda.bintray-release'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName version
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultPublishConfig "nonlocationVersionRelease"
    publishNonDefault true

    flavorDimensions "version"

    productFlavors {
        nonlocation {
            dimension "version"
        }
        location {
            dimension "version"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }



    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

configurations {
    javadocDeps
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
}

publish {
    userOrg = '*******'
    groupId = 'com.*******.android'
    artifactId = '*******'
    publishVersion = '2.0.0'
    desc = '******* sdk'
    website = 'https://github.com/*******/*******-android-public-sdk'
}
```

and here is the app's build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

def computeVersionCode = { ->
    def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    exec {
        commandLine 'git', 'rev-list', 'HEAD', '--count'
        standardOutput = stdout
    }
    return stdout.toString().trim().toInteger();
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.*******.demo"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27

        versionCode computeVersionCode()
        versionName "1.0"

        renderscriptTargetApi 20
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    signingConfigs {
        debugConfig {
            storeFile file("debug.jks")
            storePassword "*******"
            keyAlias "com.*******.android"
            keyPassword "*******"
        }

        releaseConfig {
            storeFile file("release.jks")
            storePassword "*******"
            keyAlias "com.*******.android"
            keyPassword "*******"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debugConfig
        }
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseConfig
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup:seismic:1.0.2'
    implementation 'net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK:3.7.0'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:blurry:1.0.5'

    implementation project(path: ':*******-sdk', configuration:'default')
}
```

I have been trying to fix this for 4 days and am still stuck. I've tried all of the typical solutions found on stackoverflow. This has been a cascade of problem after problem and this specific one came directly after updating how the sdk is loaded in the app's build.gradle file. I suspect something is wrong with this line where I import the sdk as a dependency (end of app's build.gradle):

```
implementation project(path: ':*******-sdk', configuration:'default')
```

but not including 'configuration: 'default'' causes another bug where the app cannot discern which buildVariant of the SDK to use.

How can I get my app up and running while also maintaining the product flavors found in the SDK?

Comment: @Alex unfortunately not. I ended up not using flavors because I wasn't able to get around this error